# Error in python package

Tags: python

I started a script which retrieves a value from a JSON object using python
but am getting these errors

```
File "c:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "c:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "c:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
```

my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
data=json.loads('{WARRANTY:"",ROOT_CATEGORYNAME:"Automobiles",}')
print data['ROOT_CATEGORYNAME']
```

Comment: The traceback seems incomplete: what is the actual error?

Comment: You do **not** have JSON data there. The key names need to be strings, not identifiers. It may be valid JavaScript but your JSON the object keeps need to be string literals (e.g. need to be quoted: `"WARRANTY"`, not `WARRANTY`).

Comment: What is the real source of your 'JSON' data? Perhaps we can help fix your real, underlying problem here.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here may be a valid JavaScript literal, but that does NOT make it valid JSON.  In valid JSON all of the keys need to be quoted, and there cannot be a trailing comma after the last element in an object or array.

In this case, the same information would look like this as JSON:

```
data=json.loads('{"WARRANTY":"","ROOT_CATEGORYNAME":"Automobiles"}')
```